# Book about a girl from a small town, involving a submarine and a government with a green storm cloud

Tags: story-identification

I read it 4 years ago. It's about a girl growing up in a ramshakle little town who signs up  to take a submarine underwater.

Later it follows an alternate story of a guy.

There is some greenstorm cloud that represented some fascist government who was taking over the world called The Green Storm.

I just cant find it anywhere.

Comment: Are you asking us to find the book on sale some where? Or are you trying to identify what the book is?

Answer (score 4):

This sounds like it's from the [Mortal Engines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predator_Cities) quartet.

It features 'predator cities' which attack others turned for resources. The article above references a Green Storm which appears to be related to one of the remaining governments.